Can't use the * operator during matrix multiplication
In my OpenGL "main.cpp" file (Windows-MinG, I've constructed view, model and model-view matrices (vMat, mMat and mvMat accordingly), which are of type glm::mat4, used in this code:
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

glm::mat4 vMat, mMat, mvMat; 

void applyMatrices(GLFWwindow* window){
   
    mvLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
    projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "proj_matrix");
    
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    aspect = (float)width / (float)height;
    projMat = glm::perspective(1.0472f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

    // glm::mat4(1.0f) : an identity matrix
    vMat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f));
    mMat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    
    mvMat = vMat * mMat;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvMat));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projMat));
}

void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {
    ...

    applyMatrices(window);
   
   ...
}

int main() {
   ...
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        display(window, glfwGetTime());
        ...
    }

   ...
}

The problem is in line
mvMat = vMat * mMat;

where multiplication of matrices happens, which if I **remove** will make the program compile successfully, but if not, will throw this error regarding the GLM library's mat4 type:
 In file included from C:.../Project/dependencies/glm/glm/glm.hpp:120,
                 from C:\Users\...\Project\src\main.cpp:5:

c:\users\...\project\dependencies\glm\glm\detail\type_mat4x4.inl: 

In instantiation of 'constexpr glm::mat<4, 4, T, Q> glm::operator*(const glm::mat<4, 4, T, Q>&, const glm::mat<4, 4, T, Q>&) [with T = float; glm::qualifier Q = (glm::qualifier)0u]':

C:\Users\...\Project\src\main.cpp:150:20:   required from here

c:\users\...\project\dependencies\glm\glm\detail\type_mat4x4.inl:642:19: error: uninitialized variable 'Result' in 'constexpr' function
   mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result;
                   ^~~~~~

For context, I'm using Windows and the MinGW compiler.
I've tried looking into iniating all three matrices **beforehand** like this:
glm::mat4 vMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 mMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 mvMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);

but this didn't change anything. I've looked whether my C++ version (C++ 20) was incompatible with the GLM's matrix workings, but even changing to older C++ version didn't help. I'm not sure if it's GLM struggling to work with my compiler (MinGW version 6.3), but I'm not sure.

glm::mat4 vMat(1.0f);?

The "implicitly defined constructor..." diagnostic is a warning, not an error. I cannot reproduce your problem on gcc from the code you posted. Please provide a minimal reproducible example, along with the complete error message that you get.

Thank you @user4581301 . I analyzed the whole message I've received from the compiler and now added in only the part that mentions the actual error, regarding the program's inability to create the "Return" value in the mat4 struct.

This is a known problem in glm, See https://github.com/g-truc/glm/pull/1264. Usually, the error should be a warning, are you compiling with some flag that forces all warnings to be treated as errors?

I think the important thing is to make sure you are using a compiler and C++ standard that are actually supported by GLM:

GCC 4.7 and higher
Intel C++ Compose XE 2013 and higher
Clang 3.4 and higher
Apple Clang 6.0 and higher
Visual C++ 2013 and higher
CUDA 9.0 and higher (experimental)
Any C++11 compiler

Here are other relevant suggestions:

Use at least c++11 to build the code with GLM. It might be a good idea to try to build the code using older standards like c++11 or c++14, instead of c++20.
Try defining the macro below to make sure types are properly aligned for SIMD operations (Single Instruction, Multiple Data):

#define GLM_FORCE_DEFAULT_ALIGNED_GENTYPES


Make sure to initialize the 4x4 matrices:

glm::mat4 vMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 mMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 mvMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);


I have GCC 6.3 (through mingw) ,tried adding the macro you've recommended, and also initialized the values for each matrix beforehand, but unfortunately, still haven't got it to work. I also tried older version such C++ 14 like you've recommended above, but still, no progress.

Seems like I needed to take the latest 'glm' branch from the https://github.com/g-truc/glm repository, which had a merged pull request addressing this exact problem with the constexpr values of the matrices.
